# Logo moves when js script inserts text in paragraph

Tags: javascript, html, css

The main problem is that my logo that is positioned next to the title with a negative margin and when a user fills in a username and proceeds the logo jumps down probably because text is inserted in the paragraph. But I can't find a solution to fix this.

HTML:

```css
#logo{
  display: flex; 
  flex-flow: row; 
  margin-top: -2.9rem;
  margin-left: 11rem;
  -ms-transform: rotate(-15deg); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-15deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: rotate(-15deg);
  justify-content: space-between;
  float: left;
  vertical-align: top;
  position:absolute;
}

#logo>img{
  max-width:230px;
  max-height:95px;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="hoofding">
      <div id="titel">
          <h1>Sudoku</h1>
      </div>

      <div id="home" >
          <div id="Welkom">
              <p id="afmeldennaam" class="hidden"></p>
          </div>
          <a id="afmelden" class="hidden">Logout</a>
      </div>
  </div>
  <nav class="hidden" id="navigatie">
      <ul>
          <!--<li><a href="#" id="home">Home</a></li>-->
          <li><a href="#" id="sudokus" class="navigatie">Sudoku</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" id="highscore" class="navigatie">Highscores</a></li>
      </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<div id="logo">
    <img src="assets/media/logo.png" alt="logo" class="visible-lg"> 
</div>
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you place your logo in the `#hoofding` element?

Comment: Because I want to have it like this: http://imgur.com/GZZCSI8

Comment: Placing the image in `#hoofding` won't prevent you from doing that.

Comment: I'll try that, thanks a lot

Comment: Why don't you make a compact thing like the `text and the logo` as a logo itself.. You can do this easily in photoshop in minutes..

Comment: If you don't have to make text an image, **don't**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should locate the logo/image in the same containing element (`#hoofding`) as the title. Then use relative positioning to position it outside of the element.

Here's a contrived example.

```js
function locate( selector, base ) {
  base = base && 1 === base.nodeType ? base : document;
  return base.querySelector( selector );
}

var btn  = locate( 'button' ),
    hb   = locate( '.header-bottom' ),
    user = locate( '.user' );

btn.addEventListener( 'click', function ( e ) {
  hb.classList.toggle( 'hide' );
  user.classList.toggle( 'hide' );
} );
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
header {
}
.header-top,
.header-bottom {
  display: flex;
  height: 75px;
  align-items: center;
}
.header-top {
  padding: 0 1rem;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}
.header-top a {
  color: white;
}
.user {
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: right;
}
.header-bottom {
  justify-content: center;
}
.hb-item {
  margin: 0 1rem;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  color: white;
  background-color: teal;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
}
h1 {
  margin: 0;
  color: teal;
}
.logo {
  display: block;
  transform: rotate( -13deg );
  position: relative;
  top: 25px;
  left: 15px;
}
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="header-top">
    <h1>Sudoku</h1>
    <img class="logo" src="http://placehold.it/100x100/fc0">
    <div class="user hide">
      <span>Welcome User!</span><a href="#">Logout</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="header-bottom hide">
    <div class="hb-item">One</div>
    <div class="hb-item">Two</div>
  </div>
</header>
<main>
  <button>Click Me!</button>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you place the logo into the title div then it will work, all you have to do then is just adjust the margins and padding.

example: 
**HTML**

```
<nav>
  <div class="brand">
  <h3>LogoName</h3>
  <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/20-flat-icons/128/crest.png" alt="">
</div>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
nav{
  background-color: black;
  height: 50px;
}
.brand{
  position: relative;
}
.brand h3{
  display: inline;
  color: white;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/q24L6ct4/2/

Comment: The problem is that I want it to look like this: http://imgur.com/GZZCSI8. And by placing it in the title div. I don't know if it will look that way or how to do that.

Comment: Exactly like that

Comment: Welp theres your example, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Use the `id='logo'` inside the `id="hoofding"`.
Put the `id='logo'` after the `id="titel"`.
The `id='logo'` doesn't need flex attributes.
The `id='logo'` doesn't need the float attribute.
The `id='logo'` doesn't need the flex-flow attribute.
Use the transform: `rotate(-15deg);` in the img tag, not in the `id='logo'`.
Delete the margins left and top from the `id='logo'`.
You can use about `margin-top: 15px;` in the img tag.